# Change User's common name in Lotus Notes 6.5

Tags: lotus-notes

I need to change a User's common name in Lotus Notes 6.5. Im logged on as administrator and i followed the steps in this link : http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/922286f472031d288525706f0065b4de?OpenDocument
But, when I do the 4th step I get “You are not authorized to perform that operation: cd-lon-dc01/Cafedirect certlog.nsf” even though im logged on as Administrator.
I searched for a workaround and found this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21174860
I have granted Editor access for the person and sufficient access to certlog.nsf but still getting “You are not authorized to perform that operation: cd-lon-dc01/Cafedirect certlog.nsf”.
Can someone please shed some light here?

Comment: Your work around advises that you give editor access to the Domino Directory, not certlog.

Answer (score 1):

This points to the ACL in certlog.nsf.  I would check again, make sure that your ID does not have explicit access which may be overriding any group access (are you checking certlog.nsf and not certlog.ntf?).  Can you go to the ACL and use the 'Effective Access' button to determine the access level your ID has.

Other things to check:

- Termination Group - make sure the ID is not in that group?
- Failing this - reboot server.
- Failing this - run fixup on the certlog database.
- Failing this - uhhh...  Not sure?